# Mysql sub-filtering

Tags: mysql, database

Let's say I have a table U of users and a table R which represents the relations (friendships) between the users. Users are able to create posts which are saved in another table P (with the user_id of the user who sent the post).

I want to retrieve all the posts made by friends of friends of friends.... of friends of a specific person. This means when e.g. I have the following setup:

```
users (U)
  id - name
  1 - Mark
  2 - Eve
  3 - Peter

relations (R)
  id_user1 - id_user2
  1 - 2
  2 - 3

posts (P)
  id - user_id - text
  1 - 1 - "Hello from Mark"
  2 - 2 - "Hello from Eve"
  3 - 3 - "Hello from Peter"
```

and I want to retrieve all messages made by Mark, i would simply select all posts with Mark's user_id. But its getting tricky when I want to retrieve all the posts made by Mark's friends. Mark has only one friend in this example, so it's kind of obvious that we would get Eve's and Mark's post here. But let's assume he has 500. I would first execute a SQL command to retrieve all his friends and then do something like

```
SELECT * from posts WHERE user_id in (2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12.....,1442);
```

Well that seems quite inefficient, but it gets even worse when I want to get the messages made by friends of his friends (or even more sub-friend layers n): 
I would make n requests (one for each layer) to retrieve the id's of his friend's friends like in the example above. Then, when I have the result of the Id's of his n-sub-friends, I would do the same as above.
For example, when we want to retrieve all posts by Marks friend's friends, we would get all the posts because Mark's friend Eve has Peter as a friend.

When the user has only 10 friends and each friend also got 10 friends, I would get 10^n ids. 
When I want to create a network containing ALL the posts of "somehow connected" friends, it would take ages to only get the ID's of all the users. And I guess the filtering with " in (....) " would take even longer when I pass like 100'000 id's.

Is there an efficient way to solve this problem?

I thought about saving some redundant data like associating every single sub-friend with every user directly in another table, but I doubt that this will work well because this would become a really gigantic table..

Comment: Don't have much time to try it out, but the following might be o interest to you http://guilhembichot.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/with-recursive-and-mysql.html . In MS-Sql I would definitely tackle the problem with Recursive Common Table Expressions. In fact I *have* done it already in MS-Sql ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *almost* it (see `temporary table` problem below):

```
DELIMITER // -- not to be used on sqlfiddle.com, use //-setting under window
CREATE TABLE allfriends (fid int)// -- this should be inside myProc as
                                    -- CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ...
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc(id int)
BEGIN
 DECLARE ncnt int;
 DECLARE cnt int;
 INSERT INTO allfriends VALUES (id);
 SET ncnt=1;
 REPEAT
  SET cnt = ncnt;
  INSERT INTO allfriends 
  SELECT id_user2 FROM relations 
    INNER JOIN allfriends ON id_user1=fid 
          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM allfriends WHERE fid=id_user2);
  SET ncnt:= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM allfriends);
 UNTIL ncnt=cnt END REPEAT;
 SELECT p.* from posts p INNER JOIN allfriends ON user_id=fid AND fid<>id;
 DELETE FROM allfriends;
END//
```

Calling

```
call myProc(1)
```

will then get you all the messages of friends of friends of friends of friends of friends of friends of friends of ... of Mark.

Ideally you should use a temporary table for `allfriends` since multiple simultaneous calls to `myProc()` will now interfere with each other, but for some reason I could not get it to work on SQLfidde. See for yourself: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28944f/1

**Edit**

Relationships can work *both ways*, so you should really be doing something like this

```
SELECT id2 FROM 
    (      SELECT id_user1 id1,id_user2 id2 FROM relations 
     UNION SELECT id_user2    ,id_user1     FROM relations) rel
    INNER JOIN allfriends ON id1=fid 
          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM allfriends WHERE fid=id2);
```

when you collect the ids in `allfriends`, see updated fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9a6b3/1

**2nd Edit**

**Got it at last!** See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b16b7a/1

```
-- DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc(id int)
BEGIN
 DECLARE ncnt int;
 DECLARE cnt int;
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE allfriends (fid int);
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE dbl (di int);
 INSERT INTO allfriends VALUES (id);
 SET ncnt=1;
 REPEAT
  SET cnt = ncnt;
  INSERT INTO dbl 
  SELECT id2 FROM 
    (      SELECT id_user1 id1,id_user2 id2 FROM relations 
     UNION SELECT id_user2,    id_user1     FROM relations) rel
    INNER JOIN allfriends ON id1=fid;
  DELETE FROM allfriends;
  INSERT INTO allfriends SELECT DISTINCT di FROM dbl;
  SET ncnt:= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM allfriends);
 UNTIL ncnt=cnt END REPEAT;
 SELECT p.* from posts p INNER JOIN allfriends ON user_id=fid AND fid<>id;
 DELETE FROM dbl;
END//
```

Since temporary tables can only be opened once in each `SELECT`-statement I am now working with two temporary tables: `allfriends` with distinct records and `dbl` with possible duplicates. The duplicates get eliminated by copying the contents of `dbl` into `allfriends` using a `SELECT DISTINCT ...` statement within the `REPEAT ... UNTIL` loop. The whole thing seems a complicated - but it works reliably!

Comment: This works perfectly! This may be a stupid question but I am still facing a problem: Using normal tables, everything works fine. 
I have never used temporary tables before so maybe I am just doing something wrong: The problem lays in `INSERT INTO allfriends  [...] INNER JOIN allfriends`. When `allfriends` is temporary, my query seems just to stop without any error report whatsoever. It seems like "[..] you cannot refer to a temporary table more than once in the same query [..]" [link](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10327) .. is there a better way then keeping two copies of allfriends?

Comment: Yes, I found the same explanation. Maybe you can solve the problem by having two temporary tables. Using one to collect new friends, clear out duplicates and then transfer them to the second one. Have not quite got it right yet and no more time to play around at the moment.